# Collision Detection of objects in certain area of camera in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a 3rd person action game where the player is a helicopter and he can shoot other objects while moving. The problem is I am trying to find the enemy objects who are inside a circle in the center of the camera and I need to track them and shoot them.

Raycast wouldn't help as i need a thicker raycast and so I tried spherecast and capsulecast.
I have a GUI element which gives the player idea on where he can shoot.When using Spherecast or Capsulecast, It is working when the enemy is near but when the enemy is far behind I guess the spherecast becomes small while traveling along z and doesn't hit the object most times.

```
if (Physics.SphereCast (startPoint, 1f, transform.forward, out hit)) {
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag ("Shootable") ){
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }
```

[image: I want to track objects which are inside the circle in the center]

I have seen raycast from camera and so i was wondering if there is something to do like circlecast from the camera which would be appropriate for this. If not how can I proceed?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking to detect enemies that are within a conical area in your camera's viewport, rather than using a sphere/raycast, you can try checking the enemy position's angle relative to the camera's forward vector. (Taken from [this Unity answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/261539/how-to-make-a-raycast-have-a-waider-range-of-hit.html).)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In order to do this we have to loop through all the enemies visible in the camera. If I have a lot of enemies in the scene...won't it affect the performance since I have to run this in update

Comment: Hm, what order of magnitude is the expected/maximum number of enemies? It's probably still worth trying, to see if your performance concerns are valid.

Comment: I am actually developing for android and so I am concerned about the performance. I think the enemies can be upto 30 or so. Still what you have suggested is very useful and I will try it out and see about the performance. Thank you so much!!

Comment: All right. Would it be all right if I expanded my comment into an answer? (So you can accept or provide feedback on it once you've tested out the suggestion.)

Comment: Yes please do that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect whether enemies lie within a conical area in front of your camera, using a `SphereCast` or `RayCast` will not be able to meet your needs.

Instead, you might consider checking the angle between an enemy's relative position and your camera's forward vector, to see if it is below a particular value, and hence within the cone.

For a 60-degree field of view, and assuming you store your enemy `Transform` components in an array/List, your code might look like:

```
foreach (Transform enemy in enemies){
    if (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, enemy.position - transform.position) < 30){
        Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions. (Answer adapted from [this Unity question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/261539/how-to-make-a-raycast-have-a-waider-range-of-hit.html).)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't experience any drastic reduction in performance and so I think I am going to stick to this method.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help out.